# Eliminar constraint para recrear tabla en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Estoy enviando un despliegue a un ambiente de calidad el cual incluye un script en sql server, en el script estoy intentando recrear una tabla, algo como esto:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tabla1') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tabla1] 
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tabla1](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fecha_registro] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tabla1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

sin embargo obtengo el siguiente error:

**No se puede quitar el objeto 'dbo.tabla1'. Hay una referencia a él en una restricción FOREIGN KEY.**

entonces me puse a revisar y encontre que la razon es porque existe una tabla secundaria que depende de la tabla1, inmediatamente pense en hacer primero el DROP a la tabla secundaria y despues a la tabla1, algo como esto:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('equivalencias.tabla1') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
        IF OBJECT_ID('equivalencias.tabla2') IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
        DROP TABLE [equivalencias].[tabla2]
        END
        
    DROP TABLE [equivalencias].[tabla1] 
END

GO

CREATE TABLE [equivalencias].[tabla1](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fecha_registro] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tabla1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

desafortunadamente es algo que no puedo hacer ya que esa tabla fue recientemente creada por otra persona fuera de mi jurisdicción, la cual tiene una llave foranea hacia la tabla1. No lo puedo hacer porque cuando se despliegue en otro ambiente eliminaria la tabla2 la cual ya tiene datos.

Intente eliminar el cons

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tabla1]
DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_tabla1]
```

pero me saca un error: **No se pudo eliminar la restricción.**

Entonces agradeceria me ayudaran, depronto forzar la eliminacion del constraint para recrear la tabla

Gracias

Comment: Al menos tres opciones: Hablas con el creador de la tabla para que elimine el constraint (lo más fácil y rápido). Obtienes el username y password de ese usuario para impersonarlo (podría hacer que te despidan). Obtener de alguna manera un usuario de administración del servidor de bases de datos y hacerlo tú mismo. Qué te impide hablar con el creador?

Comment: Elimina el `FK` de `Tabla2` que hace referencia a `Tabla1` por eso no te deja eliminar `Tabla1`. `ALTER TABLE Tabla2
DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_Tabla1;`